# Make a web kit animation work on non web kit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Hello i have made a small animation using web kit animation here.
[click to view](http://myskins.org/gangnam/index.html)

This is the animation code :

```
.log {
width:200px;
height:400px;
text-align:center;
background:url(images/gghov.png)center no-repeat;
}

.log :focus, .log:hover {
background:url(images/gg.png)center no-repeat;
-webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(8deg); }
30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-8deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-8deg); }
80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes spaceboots {
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(8deg); }
30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-8deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-8deg); }
80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
}

@keyframes spaceboots {
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(8deg); }
30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-8deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-8deg); }
80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(8deg); }
90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-8deg); }
}
```

The animation works only on Google chrome and i wanted it to work on other browsers.
But it was in vain.
can anyone help me, how to get it work on firefox and opera etc.
regards

Comment: Smells like works on only `web-kit` based browsers.BTW Cool animation Dude :)

Comment: Thank you , yeah thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery library that has a quite big range of transformation, I think it will help you :

[**Transit**](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

Comment: Thank you, i have tried using it, in integrating the animation, but i am not getting desired output.